# Training Tesseract ocr using jTessBoxEdit

Tags: ios, objective-c, tesseract

Hi i want to generate tesseract OCR training data file(tessdata). I'm using jTessBoxEditor tool(On Mac Os) for achieving this, but i have no idea how can i use this tool.And further i use the tessdata file in my ios application.
I'm  also searching for this i share the links with you 
http://vietocr.sourceforge.net/training.html

http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3

but i have no luck :( . So please share the links which provide detail/steep by by steep implementation of training file(teasdata file).

Answer (score 3):

Here is the download for the tess files
http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=tesseract-ocr-setup-3.02.02.exe&can=2&q=

I'm on the same page as you with getting this to work. Here is the tut im using.
http://www.resolveradiologic.com/blog/2013/01/15/training-tesseract/

I have learned that you need a .tif file with a .box file in the same folder to load the boxes.
For Example

```
testdata.tif
  testdata.box


anotherExample.eng.tif
  anotherExmaple.eng.box
```

To create box files easily if you don't know how do this after you download and install the tesseract files.

> ->Open command prompt and CD to your tesseract file, which is usually in your programfiles/Tesseract-ocr folder
>
> -> Run Box creator tesseract C:\location of the tif file\thetiffile.tif C:\location of the tif file\thetiffile.tif
>   batch.nochop makebox

and that should spit out the box file you need.

I'm in the process of going through and discovering. I will keep you updated. If you have any other issues let me know and maybe I can help.

Comment: Thank you very much @Exzile.
I try to implement above instruction.

Comment: If you run into a wall, post back and I'll try to help you along the way. If this answered your question mark it as answer to help others also.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to build or install all the Tesseract training executables first. Then inside jTessBoxEditor, set the appropriate Tesseract Executable location.

Comment: thanks for reply @nguyenq please can you share some link where i can get help in installation of Tesseract training executables ?